# Does not open same CRS based TIFF file and shapefile at the same time in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3

I have two file [a](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8av1o4x5iuv5qhc/kmc_main_16.rar?dl=0) & [b](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1oy9zfba5vbvru/outline%20KMC.rar?dl=0), first one is georeferenced singleband .tif file and other is .shp file with same CRS EPSG:32645. But at the time of opening, both file works fine separately, but at one window only one is shown, another one is not showing on window, but the name is shown on layers panel.

```
Name: outlinekmc.shp
Path G:.../outlinekmc.shp
Storage ESRI Shapefile
Geometry: Polygon (MultiPolygon)
CRS: EPSG:32645 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 45N - Projected
Extent: 627231.4324251519283280,2483317.2391181909479201 : 650253.3000616317149252,2503549.0619603917002678
Unit: meters
Feature: count 1


Name: kmc_main16.tif
Path: ...\kmc_main16.tif
CRS: EPSG:32645 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 45N - Projected
Extent: 88.2366249193618728,22.4461890856986592 : 88.4674844691701310,22.6346628055565056
Unit: meters
Width: 11122
Height: 9080
Data type: Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer
GDAL Driver Description: GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata: GeoTIFF
```

How can I open the two layer one above another, as both the layers corresponding to same area?

Comment: The coordinates of your tif's extent don't seem to be EPSG:32645

Comment: But the projection shows ESPG:32645. Is it looks like corrupted?

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: Try to change the layer CRS of the tiff file into EPSG:4326 in QGIS. It is just a guess but by looking at the extent it might work.

Comment: @user30184 that's no guess, that's a crisp and on point analysis of the problem. I think you should write an answer.

Comment: The EPSG:4326 part is a guess. There are also other coordinate reference systems using degrees as units. Depending on the use case it may or may not be acceptable to consider that data are in EPSG:4326 just because the result looks about correct. Myself I would try to find metadata about how the tiff file was produced or ask the data provider.

Comment: This appears to be a variant of the most frequent question here, which occurs when two layers are assigned the same spatial reference, but in fact have different ones. The solution is to determine which one is wrong (if not both), and to reassign the correct reference. To make this work, you need a known correct layer or service, then you see how well the conflicting layers each drape on it. From there it's part research and part detective work to determine what the spatial reference ought to have been. TLDR: Your GeoTIFF ought to have been 4326.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your files. As I wrote in the comments, your TIFF's coordinates are not EPSG:32645 coordinates, they are EPSG:4326. Open your TIFF's Layer Properties and set the layer's CRS to EPSG:4326 and it will be placed properly, as you can see below:

[image]